# How to include and setup Jplayer as an Audio player?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio, jplayer

I want to use a Jplayer audio player but cannot find a documention or article telling me what to include and how to set up the jplayer audio player.

Anyone who has made this before can you instruct me on how to include and get the jplayer audio player working?

In this link, I want to achieve the `jplayer as an audio player` which is second on the list: http://www.jplayer.org/latest/demos/.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Jplayer quickstart documentation](http://www.jplayer.org/latest/quick-start-guide/)